# Highcharts - add custom information to tooltip what caused price raise or price drop

Tags: highcharts

I am working a chart and need to add information to the tooltip pop-up box to each point marker. For example, I have a chart with Y: price X: date.

If the price of a product rises because of some event (for example an earthquake), I would like to show that information when someone points their mouse to that specific chart point. Is this possible in wpdatatables or highcharts?

I am a webdesigner looking for some coding help. Thanks in advance for your help.

Best Regards, 
Kevin

Tried looking for this option in jsfiddle and 
https://jsfiddle.net/Kaige/huo1vyzs/2/
https://cloud.highcharts.com/edit/249857

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {

    title: {
        text: 'Pricing chart'
    },

    subtitle: {
        text: 'Price information'
    },

    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Vitamin pricing'
        }
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle'
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            label: {
                connectorAllowed: false
            },
            pointStart: 2010
        }
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Vitamin A',
        data: [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031, 119931, 137133, 154175]
    }, {
        name: 'Vitamin B',
        data: [24916, 24064, 29742, 29851, 32490, 30282, 38121, 40434]
    }, {
        name: 'Vitamin C',
        data: [11744, 17722, 16005, 19771, 20185, 24377, 32147, 39387]
    }, {
        name: 'Vitamin D',
        data: [null, null, 7988, 12169, 15112, 22452, 34400, 34227]
    }, {
        name: 'Other',
        data: [12908, 5948, 8105, 11248, 8989, 11816, 18274, 18111]
    }],

    responsive: {
        rules: [{
            condition: {
                maxWidth: 500
            },
            chartOptions: {
                legend: {
                    layout: 'horizontal',
                    align: 'center',
                    verticalAlign: 'bottom'
                }
            }
        }]
    }

});
```

```css
#container {
 min-width: 310px;
 max-width: 800px;
 height: 400px;
 margin: 0 auto
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/series-label.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add some additional property to your data, map it by `keys` option and finally show it in a tooltip by customizing `pointFormat`:

```
series: [{
    keys: ['x', 'y', 'event'],
    data: [
        [1, 2, 'event1'],
        [2, 3, 'event2'],
        [3, 4]
    ]
}],

tooltip: {
    pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">\u25CF</span> {series.name}: <b>{point.y}</b> {point.event} <br/>'
}
```

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/acugvkqh/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.pointFormat

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.keys

Comment: Excellent, this is exactly what i needed! Thanks a lot